# Generate the pyramid for a given number?

Tags: java, for-loop, printf

i want to generate a pyramid stacks for a given number "n" ("n" - is also a height of the last pyramid). The algorithm should stack (n-1) pyramids. The result should be like this:

```
height of base pyramid: 4

          2
        2 4 2
          2
        2 4 2
      2 4 8 4 2
          2
        2 4 2
      2 4 8 4 2
   2 4 8 16 8 4 2
```

I've already a code piece to generate last pyramid:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= n - i; j++)
        System.out.printf("%5s", "");
    for (k = 1; k < i; k++)
        System.out.printf("%5d", (int) Math.pow(2, k));
    for (k = i; k >= 1; k--)
        System.out.printf("%5d", (int) Math.pow(2, k));
        System.out.println();
    }
```

any idea would be helpful.

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem with that code?

Comment: You can rewrite `(int) Math.pow(2, k)` as simply `1 << k`. If efficiency was of any importance, this is some hundreds of times faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more `for` loop in the outer most: -

```
for (int z = n - 2; z >= 0; z--)
```

So, your loop structure becomes: -

```
for (int z = n - 2; z >= 0; z--) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n - z; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++)
                System.out.printf("%5s", "");
            for (int k = 1; k < i; k++)
                System.out.printf("%5d", (int) Math.pow(2, k));
            for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--)
                System.out.printf("%5d", (int) Math.pow(2, k));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

`z` starts with `n - 2` because, the first pyramid is of length 2. And note that in the 2nd inner loop, your condition is changed to `i <= n - z`.

Now, your original set of loops runs `3 times` `(n - 2) == 2` for `n = 4`, and loop runs till from `z = 2` to `z = 0`. And it creates a pyramid of height `(n - z)`: - `(4 - 2) = 2`, `(4 - 1) = 3`, `(4 - 0) = 4` back to back.

Comment: @MukulGoel. haha :). Yeah, that's why I thought I should remind him of that also.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :-

The code you have generates a pyramid of length `n`

Enclose it inside a `for` loop that loops on say `counter=n-1` till `counter=0`

In your existing code replace value.of `n` to `n-counter+1`